# Understanding some JavaScript with a RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following js code

```
var regex = new RegExp('([\'"]?)((?:\\\\\\1|.)+?)\\1(,|$)', 'g'),
key = regex.exec( m ),
val = regex.exec( m );
```

I would like to understand it. 
In particular:

- why there are all those backslash in the definition of the RegExp? I can clearly see that `\\1` is a reference to the first saved element. Why in a new RegExp using ' and not " we need to use `\\1` and not simple `\1`?
- why there is a comma between the two definitions of `key` and `val`? I may guess that it depends on the "instances" finded using `"g"`, but it is not very clear anyway to me.

I tried to execute the code with

```
m = 'batman, robin'
```

and the result is pretty a mess, and I cannot really explain it very well.

The code is taken from JQuery Cookbook, 2.12

Comment: Use [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/), paste your regex in **expression area** on top and you'll get explanation for every character in the regex.

Comment: Yes, I know this site, but I still cannot get the meaning of putting all those backslashes; to me is useless if one just need to take the words divided by the comma. Also regexr.com does not explain why there are things like this: `\\1`.

Comment: The six backslashes means 3 reel backslashes in regex, and 1 matche a "1" character.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/ . It will tell you everything step by step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why there are all those backslash in the definition of the RegExp?

`"\\"` is a string whose value is `\`. One backslash is used as an escape, the second for the value. Then, within the regex you also need to escape the backslash character *again* because backslash characters are used to mean special things within regex.

For example

```
"\\1"
```

is a string whose value is `\1`, which, in a regular expression, matches the first captured group.

```
"\\\\"
```

is a string whose value is `\\`, which, in a regular expression, matches a single `\` character.

```
"\\\\\\1"
```

is a string whose value is `\\\1`, which, in a regular expression, matches a single `\` followed by the first captured group.

This need to escape backslashes, and then escape them again is called "double escaping". The reason you need to double escape is so that you have the correct value within the regular expression. The first escape is to make sure that the string has the correct value, the second escape is so that the regular expression matches the correct pattern.

> why there is a comma between the two definitions of key and val?

The code you posted is a variable declaration. It's easier to see when formatted:

```
var regex = ...,
    key = ...,
    val = ...;
```

Each of the variable names in the list are declared via the `var` keyword. It is the same as declaring the keywords separately:

```
var regex,
    key,
    val;

regex = ...
key = ...
val = ...
```

Which is the same as declaring each var with a different var keyword:

```
var regex = ...
var key = ...
var val = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference when writing dynamic regex objects and static regex objects. When you initialize a regex object with a string it needs to be transformed into a regex object. However, not only does the '\' holds a special value within regex objects but also within javascript strings, hence the double escape.

Edit: Regarding your second question. You can do multiple declarations with comma, like so:

```
var one = 'one',
    two = 'two',
    three = 'three';
```

2nd Edit: Here's what happens with your string once it compiles into a RegEx object.

```
/(['"]?)((?:\\\1|.)+?)\1(,|$)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is better represented as a regex literal:

```
var regex = /(['"]?)((?:\\\1|.)+?)\1(,|$)/g;
```

Backslashes are used to escape special characters. For example, if your regex needs to match a literal period, writing `.` will not work, since `.` matches any character: you need to "escape" the period with a backslash: `\.`.

Backslashes that are not themselves part of an escape sequence must be escaped, so if you want to match just a backslash in the text, you must escape it with a backslash: `\\`.

The reason your regular expression is so complicated when passed into the `RegExp` constructor is because you are representing the above regular expression as a string, which adds another "layer" of escaping. Thus, every single backslash must be escaped by yet another backslash and because the string is enclosed in single quotes, your single quote must be escaped with yet another backslash:

```
var regex = new RegExp('([\'"]?)((?:\\\\\\1|.)+?)\\1(,|$)', 'g'),
```